# jQuery accessing form values in a div that has been loaded through $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading a page into a div via jQuery in install1 .
Now the page that install1 gives me contains a few radio buttons the likes of:

```
<input name="ostype" type="radio" value="solaris">
<input name="ostype" type="radio" value="windows">
```

Now, I am trying to access the selected value in install2 .

Here is the JavaScript code for the two functions:

```
function install1() {
  $("#installer").html("<div align='center'><img src='modules/servers/flosoftdedicated/images/ajax/loading-warning.gif' border='0' alt='' /><br />Loading...</div>"); 
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'clientarea.php',
    data: 'action=productdetails&id=' + $('#serverid').val() + '&modop=custom&a=installgetos&step=1',
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(data){
        $("#installer").html(data);
        },
    });
}
function install2() {
  $("#installer").html("<div align='center'><img src='modules/servers/flosoftdedicated/images/ajax/loading-warning.gif' border='0' alt='' /><br />Loading...</div>"); 
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'clientarea.php',
    data: 'action=productdetails&id=' + $('#serverid').val() + '&modop=custom&a=installgetos&step=2&ostype=' + $("input[name='ostype']:checked").val(),
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(data){
        $("#installer").html(data);
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: install2() is called from a button in the div that is updated via install1. The code is: <input type="submit" id="start" value="Continue" onClick="install2();">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `install2` function you are **resetting** the content of the install2 div by calling `$("#installer").html("<div align='center'>...` and removing the inputs.

Remove the first line in the `install2` function.